# Does open rate of BCC affect deliverability?

Tags: email, sendgrid

Currently I BCC an internal email (records@mycompany.com) for all transactional emails, to keep records that we can easily look up

I've just realised that this might negatively affect our deliverability, since these emails are almost never opened within our records@mycompany.com email. Is this true - does the open rate of those in BCC affect sender reputation / deliverability?

Comment: Do those even go to Sendgrid? If your email server is set up properly they would just be delivered locally and never reach Sendgrid at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton They are sent via Sendgrid. E.g. if a customer, john@gmail.com makes an order, we'd send an email via Sendgrid's API to john@gmail.com, and BCC records@mycompany.com

Comment: Oh, you sent via the API, instead of SMTP. That explains it.